# iOS not sure what type of segue to use after modal VC

Tags: ios, segue

In my app I open a "advanced search" as a modal segue. But now I am not sure on what is the proper way to display the next segues.

Right now it looks like this:

*tab controller* -> *tableview* -> **searchVc(modal segue)** -> **tableview(modal segue)** -> **tableview(modal segue)**

Everything works fine, I have made my own "back buttons" in the modal VC's, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Should I instead use?:

*tab controller* -> *tableview* -> **searchVc(modal segue)** -> **navigation controller** -> **tableview(push)** -> **tableview(push)**

It is a search form that opens in a modal segue, then I can select a city which opens a tableview and after that select state which opens another table view.

Comment: You can have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/ The SplitViewController is very powerful. In a lot of cases its very nice for an universal layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine, you can use either modal or push, it's your wish. I prefer modal.